# How to do third level scraping using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have built a spider which do second level scraping using scrapy. First it scrape profile urls from search results. Then it scrape some info like web url, phone, contact name from profile url. 
Now, I want to extend this to a third level where it scrape the weburl from profile url and gets the email ids.

One challenge here is email id is not located at predictable location on websites. It can be in any pages or section. So the spider should figure out itself the page where email id is located and get the data.

How to go ahead with this?

Comment: Consider using separate spiders for separate types of websites. Other than that, you questions is quite open. Could you be more specific? What don’t you know what to do? What options have you tried or considered?

Comment: Could you update your question accordingly? Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sure. Do you have any solution?